Prediction of reduction potential behavior in amalgam
In this link, the research and comparison have been made for metal and metal amalgam reduction potential. There are some behavior that I could conclude:

Strongly reducing metal such as lithium , magnesium,... when forming amalgam with mercury tends to increase the reduction potential. For example:


lithium (Eo = -3.042 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -2.195 V)
magnesium (Eo = -2.356 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -1.980 V)


Metals with intermediate reducing power such as zinc, cadmium,... when forming amalgam with mercury does not follow any particular trend. For example:


zinc (Eo = -0.762 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -0.810 V)
cadmium (Eo = -0.403 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -0.379 V)
lead (Eo = -0.356 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -0.353 V, both from solid lead sulfate instead of  dissolved lead(II))

What is the contribution factor to the change in reduction potential of the metal as they form amalgam with mercury? Can we predict that?
The reduction potential of some metals are taken in the following website. Also, the reduction potential of lead amalgam is taken here

Where did you find the reduction potentials of amalgamated metals ? Is this potential not dependent on the relative proportion of mercury and metal in the amalgam ? Finally see you sure that zinc and magnesium get the same potential once amalgamated. Why ?

I inserted the link in the first statement, this leads to "STANDARD POTENTIALS OF AMALGAMELECTRODES IN AQUEOUS SOLUTIONS, TEMPERATURE COEFFICIENTS ANDACTIVITY COEFFICIENTS OF METALSIN MERCURY"

"zinc (Eo = -0.762 V vs Eo(amalgam) = -1.980 V)". Howvis zinc suddenlybthe same as magnesium? Is there a misprint?

The copy was a bit wrong, I edited

Yes we can predict this effect.
Two factors are involved. First, a saturated amalgam (which is rendered as the standard state in the OP's first link) is not in equilibrium with the pure metal. Metals that form amalgams also form intermetallic compounds with the mercury, as seen for instance in the sodium-mercury phase diagram given here:*

By being trapped in these intermetallic compounds, the solute metal has less fugacity/activity than the pure metal would, and when plugged into the Nernst Equation this shows up as a positive deviation in the reduction potential. Even metals such as zinc, which show "nearly equal" potentials, are found to follow the positive deviation upon closer examination.
Second, the amalgam formation potentials show a levelling effect around -2 V versus the standard hydrogen electrode, no matter how much more reducing the elemental metal might be as a solid. This is because mercury compounds with strongly electropositive metals have polar bonding, with the mercury becoming negatively charged. In effect, the observed potential for forming the amalgam and thus the equilibrated intermetallic compound reflects at least partially reduction of the mercury atoms versus reduction of the metal ions. There is some variance between mercury compounds of different metals, but as mentioned above roughly -2 V versus the standard hydrogen electrode is sufficient to set off the mercury-atom reduction.

*So in former times when mercury cathodes were used to electrolyze brine, the sodium amalgam was not used to extract metallic sodium. Rather, it was reacted with a separate water stream to give the usual sodium hydroxide product.
